# How can I change the title for each screen inside TabNavigator? - React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My stack navigator

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
       <Stack.Screen name="PageA" component={PageA} options={{title:'Page=A'}} />
       <Stack.Screen name="PageB" component={PageB} options={{title:'Page=B'}} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={MenuTabNavigator} options={{title:'Menu'}} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

and my tab navigator

```
const MenuTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="PageA" component={PageA} />
      <Tab.Screen name="PageB" component={PageB} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
);};
```

I'm using **Tab Navigator** with **Stack Navigator**.

**ScreenA**, **Screen B** and **Menu** screen in my Tabs.

I pass `MenuTabNavigator` to `StackNavigator's` **Menu** Component as you can see.

Problem:

**When I use tabs, header title stays 'Menu'.**

For example when I touch to **PageB** on tab, i expect header title should be '**PageB**' but it stays '**Menu**'.

How can I change header title for screens when i use bottom tabs?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-options-resolution.html#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state

Answer (score 3):

The approach you are using is wrong. if you go this way you have to create three StackNavigators so that you can get  three different headers. and then wrap them in a tab navigator. but this is the wrong way to use it.

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    navigation.setOptions({ title: 'Home' })
    return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
     );
 }

 function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
   navigation.setOptions({ title: 'Setting' })

 return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Menu({ navigation }) {
  navigation.setOptions({ title: 'Menu' })
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Menu</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


const StackHome = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
const StackSetting = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Setting" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
const StackMenu = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
 );
};
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="PageA" component={StackHome} options={{ title: "Home" }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="PageB" component={StackSetting} options={{ title: "Settings" 
        }} 
   />
        <Tab.Screen name="Menu" component={StackMenu} options={{ title: "Menu" }} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```